# Impala - How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Impala SQL

Tags: sql, impala

Table is:

```
+----+------+
| Id | Name |
+----+------+    
| 1  | aaa  |
| 1  | bbb  |
| 1  | ccc  |
| 1  | ddd  |
| 1  | eee  |
+----+------+
```

Required output:

```
+----+---------------------+
| Id |        abc          |
+----+---------------------+ 
|  1 | aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee |
+----+---------------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT ID,  abc = STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + name 
          FROM temp1 t1
          WHERE t1.id = t2.id
          FOR XML PATH (''))
         , 1, 1, '') from temp1 t2
group by id;
```

We know this will work in SQL Server. But when running in Impala, it will get error `AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 54:undefined: FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')`.

Does this mean Imapla does not support  FOR XML PATH?  If no, is there any other way to implement this into Impala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use group_concat() function:

[Here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_group_concat.html) you'll find the reference

```
select id, group_concat(name,',') from tablename
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks, I have found if not using comma, it will default identify it will be separated by comma. So it can be  `select id, group_concat(name) from tablename
group by id`